# Sqlite rows to column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have limited exposure to sqlite, I am commonly using SQL Server - but I am bumping my head here. I have a table called `TEAMS` and another called `PLAYERS`.

`TEAMS`:

```
TEAMID  |   TEAM NAME
```

`PLAYERS`:

```
TEAMID  |   PLAYER NAME
```

I want to select from `TEAM` and return a comma-delimited list for player names - one column all players in that column.

My goal will be to say

```
TEAM | PLAYERS
-----------------------------------------
WAVE | TIM SMITH, TREY BROWN, JOHN SMITH
BEARS| AMY JOHNS, BILL BRICE, KYLE BROWN
```

I am not sure how to issue the query to get when I need here - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate all values in a group, use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT TeamName,
       group_concat(PlayerName)
FROM Teams JOIN Players USING (TeamID)
GROUP BY TeamID
```